# Multiply a Matrix by a Vector and return a Vector

Tags: c++

Ok, i'm hoping someone can help me out here. I'm trying to multiply a Vector3 by a Matrix4 technically...

My FMatrix

```
struct FMatrix
{
struct FPlane                                      XPlane;                                                  
struct FPlane                                      YPlane;                                                  
struct FPlane                                      ZPlane;                                                  
struct FPlane                                      WPlane;                                                  
};
```

So Each FPlane has X,Y,Z,W

Making them FMatrix.XPlane.X FMatrix.XPlane.Y etc etc

Here's the code I have so far and I understand that my Vector3 technically needs transformed to a Vector4 using 1 or 0 for my W.

```
FVector2D get2dPoint(FVector worldloc) 
{
  FMatrix mat = mHUD->ViewProjectionMatrix;
  FVector res;
  float x = worldloc.X;
  float y = worldloc.Y;
  float z = worldloc.Z;

  res.X = (mat.XPlane.X*x) + (mat.YPlane.X*y) + (mat.ZPlane.X*z) + (mat.WPlane.X * 1);
  res.Y = (mat.XPlane.Y*x) + (mat.YPlane.Y*y) + (mat.ZPlane.Y*z) + (mat.WPlane.Y * 1);
  res.Z = (mat.XPlane.Z*x) + (mat.YPlane.Z*y) + (mat.ZPlane.Z*z) + (mat.WPlane.Z * 1);

  float winX = round(((res.X + 1.0f) / 2.0f) * mHUD->uiResolution.X);
  float winY = round(((1.0f - res.Y) / 2.0f) * mHUD->uiResolution.Y);    
  return{ winX, winY };
}
```

As I'm sure most of you can see I'm trying to make a world to screen function. I am using boost library and I saw something about ublas and matrix's but I definitely got lost in that, but if that helps you to help me I'm cool with it. So either an example with normal c++ or using boost functions is fine with me.

Comment: I think more information is needed, to you have a vector class, along with a matrix class, because if you want to do something like M * V = V, then you need to setup friend relationships, etc... between the classes.  I remember doing this back in school, I also know that I have these pieces of code lying around somewhere.

Comment: What is your question?